# How do I link to the directories of the libraries needed to build a static tor binary on Ubuntu?

Tags: tor-install, build

```
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-nss --enable-static-tor --with-openssl-dir=usr/bin/openssl --with-libevent-dir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent-2.1.so.7.0.1 --with-zlib-dir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.13
```

gives me the following error:

```
checking for libevent directory... (system)
checking whether we need extra options to link libevent... (none)
checking event2/event.h usability... yes
checking event2/event.h presence... yes
checking for event2/event.h... yes
checking event2/dns.h usability... yes
checking event2/dns.h presence... yes
checking for event2/dns.h... yes
checking event2/bufferevent_ssl.h usability... yes
checking event2/bufferevent_ssl.h presence... yes
checking for event2/bufferevent_ssl.h... yes
configure: error: "You must specify an explicit --with-libevent-dir=x option when using --enable-static-libevent"
```

I think I have incorrectly chosen the directories of the libraries.
I linked to the files because I have not found any directories?
I am on an ubuntu derivative. How should I rewrite this command for it to succeed?

Comment: See this: https://github.com/cretz/tor-static/blob/master/build.go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old pain in the ass :) You **have to** compile the libraries required by hand, actually - and install them on the system you're using for building stuff. You will break nothing on your build host, but it's the *only pain-proof* way to build TOR statically. And in your line - you need to point to the *directory* containing the xxx.a *file*, not to the xxx.so *file*. dot-so is a Shared Object